# Arrange order "run_1" followed by "run_2" instead of "run_11"

Tags: r

I have a tibble like below.

```
test <- tibble(run = c("run_1","run_2", "run_3", "run_11", "run_111", "run_4"))

test %>% arrange(run)
```

gives me

```
1   run_1
2  run_11
3 run_111
4   run_2
5   run_3
6   run_4
```

but I want

```
1  run_1
2  run_2
3  run_3
4  run_4
5  run_11
6  run_111
```

Any way to solve it?

Comment: Can you re-label them `run_01`, `run02`, etc.?

Comment: Probably missing the context ..but didn't quite get why you want the original order in `test` after arrange?

Comment: a bad example in the beginning, sorry.

Comment: No problem . Added a new solution with this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

Using `mixedorder` function:

```
library(gtools)
test <- tibble(run = c("run_1","run_2", "run_3", "run_11", "run_111", "run_4"))
test[mixedorder(test$run),]
# A tibble: 6 × 1
      run
    <chr>
1   run_1
2   run_2
3   run_3
4   run_4
5  run_11
6 run_111
```

**Original answer:**

Using `mixedsort` function:

```
library(gtools)
test <- c("run_1","run_2", "run_11", "run_3")
mixedsort(test)
[1] "run_1"  "run_2"  "run_3"  "run_11"
```

Comment: Right, `mixedsort` does't help here. But `mixedorder` does. I edited my answer. Thanks @user28575

Answer (score 2):

you can use mixedsort in the gtools package:

```
gtools::mixedsort
```

Answer (score 1):

how about using tidyr/dplyr:

```
test %>% separate(run, into=c("prefix","suffix")) %>% arrange(as.numeric(suffix)) %>% mutate(new_test=apply( . , 1 , paste , collapse = "_" ))

 A tibble: 6 × 3
  prefix suffix new_test
   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>
1    run      1    run_1
2    run      2    run_2
3    run      3    run_3
4    run      4    run_4
5    run     11   run_11
6    run    111  run_111
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the part of the string that you wish to sort by, then sort by that

```r
library(tibble)
test <- tibble(run = c("run_1","run_2", "run_3", "run_11", "run_111", "run_4"))

test %>% 
  mutate(num = as.integer(gsub("^[^0-9]*(\\d*)", "\\1", run))) %>% 
  arrange(num)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>       run   num
#>     <chr> <int>
#> 1   run_1     1
#> 2   run_2     2
#> 3   run_3     3
#> 4   run_4     4
#> 5  run_11    11
#> 6 run_111   111
```